# How do I extract a string using a regex in a shell script?

Tags: regex, shell, curl

I want to extract part of a string using a regular expression. For example, how do I extract the domain name from the `$name` variable?

```
name='<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>'

domain_name=...  # apply some regex on $name
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Using [bash regular expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs):

```
re="http://([^/]+)/"
if [[ $name =~ $re ]]; then echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; fi
```

**Edit** - OP asked for explanation of syntax.  [Regular expression syntax](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a large topic which I can't explain in full here, but I will attempt to explain enough to understand the example.

```
re="http://([^/]+)/"
```

This is the regular expression stored in a bash variable, `re` - i.e. what you want your input string to match, and hopefully extract a substring.  Breaking it down:

- `http://` is just a string - the input string must contain this substring for the regular expression to match
- `[]` Normally square brackets are used say "match any character within the brackets".  So `c[ao]t` would match both "cat" and "cot".  The `^` character within the `[]` modifies this to say "match any character *except* those within the square brackets.  So in this case `[^/]` will match any character apart from "/".
- The square bracket expression will only match one character.  Adding a `+` to the end of it says "match 1 or more of the preceding sub-expression".  So `[^/]+` matches 1 or more of the set of all characters, excluding "/".
- Putting `()` parentheses around a subexpression says that you want to save whatever matched that subexpression for later processing.  If the language you are using supports this, it will provide some mechanism to retrieve these submatches.  For bash, it is the BASH_REMATCH array.
- Finally we do an exact match on "/" to make sure we match all the way to end of the fully qualified domain name and the following "/"

Next, we have to test the input string against the regular expression to see if it matches.  We can use a bash conditional to do that:

```
if [[ $name =~ $re ]]; then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

In bash, the `[[ ]]` specify an extended conditional test, and may contain the `=~` bash regular expression operator.  In this case we test whether the input string `$name` matches the regular expression `$re`.  If it does match, then due to the construction of the regular expression, we are guaranteed that we will have a submatch (from the parentheses `()`), and we can access it using the BASH_REMATCH array:

- Element 0 of this array `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}` will be the entire string matched by the regular expression, i.e. "http://www.google.com/".
- Subsequent elements of this array will be subsequent results of submatches.  Note you can have multiple submatch `()` within a regular expression - The `BASH_REMATCH` elements will correspond to these in order.  So in this case `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` will contain "www.google.com", which I think is the string you want.

Note that the contents of the BASH_REMATCH array only apply to the last time the regular expression `=~` operator was used.  So if you go on to do more regular expression matches, you **must** save the contents you need from this array each time.

This may seem like a lengthy description, but I have really glossed over several of the intricacies of regular expressions.  They can be quite powerful, and I believe with decent performance, but the regular expression syntax is complex.  Also regular expression implementations vary, so different languages will support different features and may have subtle differences in syntax.  In particular escaping of characters within a regular expression can be a thorny issue, especially when those characters would have an otherwise different meaning in the given language.

---

Note that instead of setting the `$re` variable on a separate line and referring to this variable in the condition, you can put the regular expression directly into the condition.  However in [bash 3.2](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS), the rules were changed regarding whether quotes around such literal regular expressions are required or not.  Putting the regular expression in a separate variable is a straightforward way around this, so that the condition works as expected in all bash versions that support the `=~` match operator.

Comment: What if you need to do a case insensitive match, or change other flags?

Comment: FYI Bash does not understand non-capturing groups (E.g. `(?:...)`). so I just used the index for the group I was interested in `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}`, Example,\
```
path=$1
re="(create|identical) (.+)"
comp=$(echo $path | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}' | awk -F"." '{print $1}')
res=`yo jest:test $path --componentName $comp 2>&1`
if [[ $res =~ $re ]];
  then
    src=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    dest=$(echo $src | awk '{sub("__tests__/", ""); print}');
    dest="tests/$dest"
    mv $src $dest
    echo "Created $dest"
fi
```

Answer (score 9):

One way would be with `sed`.  For example:

```
echo $name | sed -e 's?http://www\.??'
```

Normally the `sed` regular expressions are delimited by `/', but you can use '?' since you're searching for '/'.  Here's another bash trick. @DigitalTrauma's answer reminded me that I ought to suggest it.  It's similar:

```
echo ${name#http://www.}
```

(DigitalTrauma also gets credit for reminding me that the "http://" needs to be handled.)