# unable to extract data inside square brackets in bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, logic

I have input(output.txt with almost 2000lines) like

```
lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum
["a","b","c","d"]
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
["e","f","g","h"]
```

My output1.txt should be

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
```

First, i am trying to put all values inside [] in one file. But ultimately my aim is to achieve output1.txt. It would be great if someone help me to achieve in one shot(extracting data inside [] and removing "" and comma and place values in each line)

My code is as of now

```
    reg="\[([^]]+)\]"
    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    if [[ $line = ~$reg ]] ; then echo "$line" >>      home/hdpsrvc/sandeep/hbase/output1.txt ; fi
    done < /home/hdpsrvc/sandeep/hbase/output.txt
```

File is not created in specified path and also on the terminal there is no error. I followed following stackoverflow links to write above code

[shell script. how to extract string using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737675/shell-script-how-to-extract-string-using-regular-expressions)
[Regular expression to extract text between square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets)

Comment: You used `= ~$reg` instead of `=~ $reg`. You'll make things easier on yourself if you test the code you link to first to make sure it works, then gradually adapt it and see exactly at which point you get stuck

Comment: Awesome..Thanks.You are right. Can you tell me how i should extract like output1.txt

Comment: `reg="\[([^]]+)\]"
reg1="(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1"
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
if [[ $line =~ $reg ]]  
then 
if [[ $line =~ $reg1 ]] 
then 
echo "1"
echo "$line" >> /home/hdpsrvc/sandeep/hbase/output1.txt 
fi
fi
done < /home/hdpsrvc/sandeep/hbase/output.txt`

I am getting error message
extract1.sh: line 3: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
extract1.sh: line 13: syntax error: unexpected end of file   

I followed this link[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `awk` can do this easily:

```
cd /home/hdpsrvc/sandeep/hbase

awk -F'[][," ]+' '/\[.*\]/{for (i=2; i<NF; i++) print $i}' output.txt > output1.txt
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
```

Comment: No, its taking input from output.txt(line variable reads each and every line from output.txt). so now can you tell me where to put output.txt?

Comment: i understood output1.txt is my output. But my input file is output.txt. If you see my code there are 2 different files. I am asking about output.txt. Thanks for your time and effort

Comment: sorry for troubling you. my code in the question is in extract.sh. So can i remove my entire code and place your awk code?

Comment: Yes of course, remove all that code and use this awk. [Also check this demo](http://ideone.com/0QsSu4)

Comment: ok thanks for nice demo. But as i am newbie.. i have all these questions. Thanks for your patience. you have used lorem ipsum text directly in your cat command, but i need it to be in file name. so does the following work? cat << "output.txt" | awk -F'[][,"]+' '/\[.*\]/{for (i=2; i<NF; i++) print $i}' output1.txt. When i pasted your code, nothing is happening in my terminal and output1.txt is also not created

Comment: very very sorry. just saw your update code. i will try and let u know. thanks

Comment: wow. super. Thanks for your time and effort. Also a very big thanks for revising your answer according to my requirement. I am accepting your answer. Thanks once again

Comment: sorry to bother you again. I have closely seen my input so there is one space after comma like ["a", "b", "c"]. so that is why my output is having empty line after each element. do you have any fix for this?