# How do I use a regex in a shell script?

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I want to match an input string (contained in the variable `$1`) with a regex representing the date formats `MM/DD/YYYY` and `MM-DD-YYYY`.

```
REGEX_DATE="^\d{2}[\/\-]\d{2}[\/\-]\d{4}$"
 
echo "$1" | grep -q $REGEX_DATE
echo $?
```

The `echo $?` returns the error code `1` no matter the input string.

Comment: This is possible a kind of duplicate of:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737675/shell-script-how-to-extract-string-using-regular-expressions

Comment: That's because `$?` reports on the first command in the pipe chain, which is echo - the echo will obviously succeed, so you get a `1` exit code. try `grep $pattern <<< $1` instead.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1221833/440558) for one solution.

Comment: Always check your program's documentation to see what style of regular expressions are accepted.

Comment: @MarcB err, no, it's the other way around -- `$?` is the **last** exit status in the pipeline

Answer (score 125, accepted):

To complement the existing helpful answers:

Using **Bash's own regex-matching operator, `=~`**, is a faster alternative in this case, given that you're only matching a single value already stored in a variable:

```
set -- '12-34-5678' # set $1 to sample value

kREGEX_DATE='^[0-9]{2}[-/][0-9]{2}[-/][0-9]{4}$' # note use of [0-9] to avoid \d
[[ $1 =~ $kREGEX_DATE ]]
echo $? # 0 with the sample value, i.e., a successful match
```

Note that `=~` even allows you to define **capture groups** (parenthesized subexpressions) whose matches you can later access through Bash's special **`${BASH_REMATCH[@]}` arra**y variable.

**Portability caveat**:

- While **`=~` supports EREs** (*extended* regular expressions), it **also supports the *host platform's specific extensions*** - it's **a rare case of Bash's behavior being *platform-dependent***; examples:

  - `\d` to match a *digit* is supported on macOS, but not on Linux - use `[0-9]`
  - `\<` /`\>` and `\b` (*word-boundary assertions*) are supported on Linux, but not on macOS, where you must use `[[:<:]]` / `[[:>:]]` - none these are POSIX-compliant
  - *Backreferences* (e.g. `\1`) work on Linux, but not on macOS (per POSIX, they're only supported in *basic* regexes (BREs)).

    - If your scripts are designed to run *Linux* only, you can use a backreference to make matching more robust, by capturing the specific character used as the first separator in a capture group (`(...)`) and referring to it later with `\1` to ensure that the *same* separator is matched:<sup>Thanks, [ibonyun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4171481/ibonyun)</sup>

      ```
      kREGEX_DATE='^[0-9]{2}([-/])[0-9]{2}\1[0-9]{4}$'
      ```
- To remain **portable** (in the context of Bash), stick to the **[POSIX ERE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04)** specification.

Further notes:

- `$kREGEX_DATE` is used *unquoted*, which is necessary for the regex to be recognized as such (quoted parts would be treated as *literals*).
- While not always necessary, it is advisable to store the regex in a variable first, because Bash has trouble with regex *literals* containing `\`.

  - E.g., on Linux, where `\<` is supported to match word boundaries, `[[ 3 =~ \<3 ]] && echo yes` doesn't work, but `re='\<3'; [[ 3 =~ $re ]] && echo yes` does.
- I've changed variable name `REGEX_DATE` to `kREGEX_DATE` (`k` signaling a (conceptual) constant), so as to ensure that the name isn't an all-uppercase name, because [all-uppercase variable names should be avoided to prevent conflicts with special environment and shell variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01).

Comment: I'd use `^[0-9]{2}([-/])[0-9]{2}\1[0-9]{4}$` instead.  It's the same except that the 1st delimiter is inside a capturing group `([-/])` and the 2nd delimiter is a back-reference to whatever that capturing group matches `\1`.  That way you're guaranteed to only match strings where the delimiters are the same which will avoid false positives for strings like `"12-34/5678"` that coincidently look similar to dates but could mean something completely different.

Comment: @ibonyun, that is preferable - but _not portable_ (which you may or may not care about in a given use case): it works on Linux, but not on macOS, for instance. I'm trying to keep the answer portable, but I've made the pitfalls of using platform-specific extensions clearer in the answer, and I've added your regex as a Linux-alternative.

Answer (score 31):

I think this is what you want:

```
REGEX_DATE='^\d{2}[/-]\d{2}[/-]\d{4}$'

echo "$1" | grep -P -q $REGEX_DATE
echo $?
```

I've used the -P switch to get perl regex.

Comment: just to clarify, `-P` is not guaranteed to be supported in all distros.  so if portability is a concern, you'll want to avoid it.

Comment: In which case, @MikeFrysinger 's solution is preferable. This one has the slight attraction of using the original regex, give or take some escaping.

Answer (score 13):

the problem is you're trying to use regex features not supported by grep.  namely, your `\d` won't work.  use this instead:

```
REGEX_DATE="^[[:digit:]]{2}[-/][[:digit:]]{2}[-/][[:digit:]]{4}$"
echo "$1" | grep -qE "${REGEX_DATE}"
echo $?
```

you need the `-E` flag to get [ERE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) in order to use `{#}` style.

Comment: ++; note that if you `\ `-escaped the `{` and `}` instances, this particular regex would have worked without `-E`, as a BRE (basic regex) as well; as a non-portable aside: BSD/OSX `grep` - unlike GNU `grep` - actually does support `\d`.

Comment: you are certainly correct; however i prefer `-E` over `\` everywhere as it makes the code much more readable, and it's in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html).

Answer (score 0):

Below is example shell script, which we used for pre-commit hook to enforce branch name

```
#!/bin/bash
BRANCH_NAME=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

BRANCH_REGEX='^(feature|hotfix|chore)/MYAPP-[0-9]+(_|-).*$'
 
if ! [[ $BRANCH_NAME =~ $BRANCH_REGEX ]]; then
   echo "Error: Invalid branch name $BRANCH_NAME."
   echo "You can run below command to rename branch"
   echo "git branch -m old_branch new_branch"
fi
```