# Get files by bytes signature from swap using bash

Tags: bash, shell, hex, swap

I have a huge file (dump of swap-file) with random bytes data. I need to get files starts and ends with exact bytes in hexadecimal, which I know. For example jpeg starts with `FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46` and ens with `FF D9`. Moreover, I need to do this using bash script.  Can You give some advices how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic advice is: do not use bash for this. Although it is possible, `bash` is not the tool for this. You are better of writing short C-code.

If you really insist on doing it in bash,

```
while LANG=C IFS= read -r -d '' -n 1 char ;do
    #do your test for the next byte
done
```

reads the bytes one-by-one.

Alternatively, you may use the output of `od -x` to pass through some loops.

But that is really only if you must use bash.

Comment: I have already done this using C# and python, but unfortunately I need to do this using bash =(

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use Bash for this. If you **must** use bash, then maybe try regex?

```
JPG_REGEX='FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46 [\w|\s]+ FF D9' #this matches any jpeg file

echo <name of your file here> | grep -P -q $JPG_REGEX
```

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919103/how-do-i-use-a-regex-in-a-shell-script).