# bash - returning value based on process condition

Tags: linux, bash

i stumbled in a confusing way of conditionally returning value based on variable. I would like to check if process is successful then echo "process success", but if it's failed, i want to check specific error message then return the error message,

```
ERRMSG="$(cd /nonexist 2>&1)"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    if [ -z "$ERRMSG|grep -o 'No such file or directory'|head -1" ]
    then
    echo "empty" >> $FQLOGNAME
    else
    echo $ERRMSG|grep -o 'No such file or directory'|head -1 >> $FQLOGNAME
    fi
else
echo "success" >> $FQLOGNAME
fi
```

Please advice,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `grep` to check if a string contains a substring.  The built-in pattern matching in Bash is sufficient.  This code should do something close to what you want:

```
if ERRMSG=$(cd /nonexist 2>&1) ; then
    echo 'process success'
elif [[ $ERRMSG == *'No such file or directory'* ]] ; then
    echo 'No such file or directory'
else
    echo 'empty'
fi >> "$FQLOGNAME"
```

See the [Conditional Constructs section of the Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) for details of the pattern matching capabilities of `[[...]]`.

I've retained the `ERRMSG` and `FQLOGNAME` variables, but note that it's best to avoid `ALL_UPPERCASE` variable names.  There is a danger that they will clash with environment variables or Bash builtin variables.  See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375).

To find error messages defined by a pattern in multi-line error messages, and only print the first one, you can use regular expression matching (`=~`) in `[[...]]`.  To provide a concrete example, this code assumes that error messages consist of 'ERROR' followed by one or more spaces followed by a decimal number:

```
# Example function for testing
function dostuff
{
    printf 'Output line A\n'
    printf 'Encountered ERROR 29\n' >&2
    printf 'Output line B\n'
    printf 'Encountered ERROR 105\n' >&2
    printf 'Output line C\n'

    return 1
}

# Regular expression matching an error string
readonly error_rx='ERROR +[0-9]+'

if ERRMSG=$(dostuff 2>&1) ; then
    echo 'process success'
elif [[ $ERRMSG =~ $error_rx ]] ; then
    printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
else
    echo 'empty'
fi >> "$FQLOGNAME"
```

It appends 'ERROR 29' to the log file.

For more information about Bash's built-in regular expression matching see [mklement0's answer to "How do I use a regex in a shell script?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35924143/4154375).

Comment: it's a sample error message, because i would like to execute java script that possibly return multiple error message if failed, therefore i need to grep and pick first match only, is it applicable with your solution to my case?

Comment: I've added code that attempts to meet the clarified requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Make it simpler and easier:

```
if ! ERRMSG=$(cd /nonexist 2>&1); then
     if <<<"$ERRMSG" grep -q 'No such file or directory'; then
           # if the error string contains the message 'No such file or directory'
           echo "empty" >> "$FQLOGNAME"
     else
           printf "Unhandled cd error: %s" "$ERRMSG" >> "$FQLOGNAME"
     fi
else
     echo "process success" >> "$FQLOGNAME"
fi
```

1. `if` statements checks for the return status of a COMMAND. `[` or `test` is just a command, which return a status. The return status of assignment is the same as command status. What I mean, is that `out=$(cmd); if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then` is the same as `if out=$(cmd); then`.
2. Using HERE-strings is a bit better than `echo "$string"`. Echo is not that much portable, better get used to `printf "%s" "$string"` which is a portable way. However HERE-strings puts additional EOF at the end of the stream, which sometimes breaks `while read` loops, but for most cases works ok.
3. Don't `if [ -z "$(echo smth | grep ..)" ]; then`. You can just check grep return status, just `if echo smth | grep ...; then` or with HERE-strings `if <<<"smth" grep -q ...; then` or `if grep -q ... file; then`. The `-q` option which has `--quiet` or `--silent` alternatives makes grep produce no output.
4. The quoting is not needed when assigning a variable from a single command substitution. `tmp="$(...)"` is just the same as `tmp=$(...)`.

Comment: I'm not altogether convinced this is "simpler and easier".

Comment: thanks, i will try this, but is this grep only result for first match?

Comment: and what does it means with <<< ? sorry i'm not really familiar with bash scripting

Comment: `<<<"$string"` is called HERE-string and it is the same as `echo "$string" | ` or more professional `printf "%s" "$string"`.  If I understood you correctly, you wanted to print "empty" to the log file if the ERRMSG contains "No such file or directory". So the script does, reading from the second line: if ERRMSG contains/greps 'No such file or directory, then print empty to FQLOGNAME eles print unhandled cd error to FQLOGNAME.