# Parsing substrings from a command

Tags: bash, shell

I'm looking for some help in parsing a substring from the output of a command.

The output of the command looks like this (command is `cerbot-auto certificates` and related to letsencrypt certificates:

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Found the following certs:
  Certificate Name: amadev.domain1.com
    Domains: amadev.domain1.com rcpdev8.domain1.com 
    Expiry Date: 2019-05-12 14:51:44+00:00 (VALID: 87 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/amadev.domain1.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/amadev.domain1.com/privkey.pem
  Certificate Name: amadev.domain2.com
    Domains: amadev.domain2.com rcpdev8.domain2.com
    Expiry Date: 2019-05-07 13:12:11+00:00 (VALID: 82 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/amadev.domain2.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/amadev.domain2.com/privkey.pem
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

I'm looking to extract the certificate name and the domains but am struggling the with the bash substring commands.  I think I should be able to get what I need using cut and then manipulating that result but I haven't been successful yet.

It doesn't matter to me if I end up with an array of some sort with all values or if the code loops and does each one individually overwriting the previous but I need something that ends up with variables holding values that look like this:

```
certificate="amadev.domain1.com"
domains="amadev.domain1.com,rcpdev8.domain1.com"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple grep/cut solution  :

```
cerbot-auto certificates | grep -E 'Certificate Name|Domains' | cut -d':' -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean) pure Bash code:

```
#! /bin/bash

# Regular expressions to match the required fields
name_rx='^Certificate[[:space:]]+Name:[[:space:]]+(.*)$'
domains_rx='^Domains:[[:space:]]+(.*)$'

certbot_auto_output=$(certbot-auto certificates)

# (Assuming a standard $IFS) 'read' will strip leading and trailing whitespace
while read -r line ; do
    if [[ $line =~ $name_rx ]] ; then
        certificate=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    elif [[ $line =~ $domains_rx ]] ; then
        domains=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        domains=${domains// /,}     # Replace spaces with commas
        printf 'certificate="%s"\n' "$certificate"
        printf 'domains="%s"\n' "$domains"
    fi
done <<<"$certbot_auto_output"
```

See [mkelement0's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35924143/4154375) to [How do I use a regex in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35919103/4154375) for information about using Bash regular expressions.

See [Substituting part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Substituting_part_of_a_string) for information about `${var//.../...}`.

See [Command line: <<< instead of <<](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/76402/264812) for information about `<<<"..."` ("here string").

Answer (score 0):

Used funkyjelly's response to come up with the following:

```
# Store each certificate name and list of domains in an array
mapfile -t certificate_names < <(/opt/certbot-auto certificates | grep 'Certificate Name:' | cut -d':' -f2) 
mapfile -t domains < <(/opt/certbot-auto certificates | grep 'Domains:' | cut -d':' -f2) 

len=${#certificate_names[@]}

for (( i=0; i<$len; i++ ))
do
    #replace spaces with commas and drop the first comma
    fqdns=${domains[$i]}
    fqdns=${fqdns// /,}
    fqdns="${fqdns:1}"

    # Renew the cert
    /opt/certbot-auto certonly --manual --agree-tos --manual-public-ip-logging-ok --email oueemail@example.com --preferred-challenges dns --manual-auth-hook update-txt-records.sh --manual-cleanup-hook clean-txt-records.sh --cert-name ${certificate_names[$i]} -d $fqdns --expand --noninteractive

done
```