# Bash compatible regex (with groups)

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to do a simple script with a regex. This regex works in texts editors and online regex checkers. But I can't find how to make it work on bash.

I need to capture groups, by the way.

Example text:

```
2020-03-06 10:00:07 Test2: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soape...
2020-03-06 10:00:13 Test2: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soape...
```

This is my script. It reads each line and creates a file named DATE_HOUR.xml filled with the text until the end of the line (after formatting it):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
: ${1?"USO: $0 NOMBRE-DEL-ARCHIVO"} #If no args passed

regex="^(\d*-\d*-\d*)\s(\d*:\d*:\d*)\s(\w*): (.*)$" #This one is working on editors

mkdir -p out
while read line
do
   if [[ $line =~ $regex ]] #IT NEVER ENTERS HERE
    then
        date="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"   #DATE
        time="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"   #TIME
        time="${time/:/-}"          #REPLACE : with -
        name="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"   #I DO NOT USE IT BY NOW
        text="${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"   #TEXT
        echo $text | xmllint --format - > out/$date"_"$time.xml
    fi
done < $1
```

I've tried this regex, but it sure has errors:

```sh
regex="^([[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}) ([[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}) ([[a-zA-Z0-9]]{1,}): (*{1,})$"
```

Thank you.

Comment: The regular expressions supported by Bash are [POSIX Extended Regular Expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) (ERE).  See [mkelement0's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35924143/4154375) to [How do I use a regex in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35919103/4154375).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot use "Perl-style" shorthand such as `\d` and `\s` in Bash. Your final attempt is close but contains a few errors, such as `[[a-zA-Z0-9]]` (should only have one pair of `[]`) and `*{1,}` (not 100% clear on what this does but it's not what you want!).

This pattern can be used instead:

```
regex='([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}) ([a-zA-Z0-9]+): (.*)'
```

I'm using `[0-9]` to match the digits - you could use `[[:digit:]]` instead but it doesn't look like you need support for any characters outside the range `0-9`. I also replaced `\s` with a simple space (you could use `[[:blank:]]` to match spaces or tabs if that's a possibility).

Regarding the anchors `^` and `$`, you probably don't need them:

- `^` is only necessary if you want to avoid lines that match the pattern but **don't** start with it (it looks like all your lines start with it, in which case this wouldn't be needed)
- `$` is irrelevant as your pattern ends with `.*` which will consume the whole rest of the line

Testing it out:

```
$ line='2020-03-06 10:00:07 Test2: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soape...'
$ regex='([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}) ([a-zA-Z0-9]+): (.*)'
$ [[ $line =~ $regex ]] && echo yes
yes
$ printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"
2020-03-06 10:00:07 Test2: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soape...
2020-03-06
10:00:07
Test2
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soape...
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew about Perl-style. That's why I tried the second regex with no luck (I forgot about the dot before the asterisk, lol). Also, I just noticed that using `^` and `$` on a string that will always be a single line is not necesary.

Comment: @Hache_raw I edited my answer to add a bit more explanation about the anchors to the start and end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having headache with regex why do not try `awk`:

```
while read line
do
filename=$(awk '{print $1"_"$2}' <<< "$line")
awk '{$1="";$2="";$3=""; gsub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"",$0); print}'  <<< "$line" |xmllint --format - >out/${filename}.xml
done < $1
```

If you do not want colon in filename you can replace the line to be:

```
filename=$(awk '{gsub(/:/,"",$2); print $1"_"$2}' <<< "$line")
```

What this code do is sample. First it make loop thru all the lines (from your code). Then I assign to `filename` first and second variables concatenated with underscode.

Next in second `awk` I assign empty string to first 3 tokens, then `gsub` replace the spaces (between first and second tokens, between second and third token and  third token and forth token) with nothing. If I do not do this some versions of `xmllint` will complain. Then I print the line. The construction `<<< "$line"` mean to use to content of $line and create filehandler and use it as input file.

Comment: `cat $line` is wrong here. Use either `echo "$line"` or `awk ... <<< "$line"` instead.

Comment: Wow, nice approach. I upvoted your answer but I'll mark as correct the other one since it uses my code and explains things. Looking at your code I can't even guess what's happening. Two things: 1) I didn't knew that I could use colons in filenames. 2) I don't know why but `print $1_$2` is not printing the underscore. 

If you could explain a little the code, it would be great! Thanks.

Comment: @Hache_raw, code corrected, now should print underscore. If you do not like colons they can be removes. WIll add how to do