# Why does my regex match substrings instead of the full string?

Tags: bash, shell

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
echo $a
if [[ "$a" =~ release* ]]; then
    echo "not valid branch allowed to be created"
    exit 1
fi
```

What I am trying to achieve is that only if the value of `a` starts with the string `release`, then the script should exit with status 1.

I want to make sure I validate the value of `a` against a regex that always starts with the string `release` and can have any other characters or numbers or special characters after that. However, I see in the script that if `a` includes the string `release` anywhere in its value, the script still matches it with the regex and prints the value under the echo.

How do I get the regex right here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to anchor the RE to only match at the beginning of the string. You also don't want that `*` at the end; it means *match 0 or more of the previous thing*, in this case an e.

```
[[ "$a" =~ ^release ]]
```

You could also use a glob pattern instead of a regular expression:

```
[[ "$a" = release* ]]
```

Comment: Thanks i actually figured out using 
if [[ "$a" == release* ]]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Bash regular expression support but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919103/how-do-i-use-a-regex-in-a-shell-script) post may help and has some other best practice tips.

Aside, don't you need a caret to match the start of the string?  Also, any subsequent characters is period asterisk (i.e. period being any one character, asterisk being zero or more of the previous character).

```
    ^release.*
```