# how to remove one word probably with comma in a string using bash?

Tags: bash

The string is `test-image,test-image-v1,test-image-v2,...`, sometimes test-image maybe in the end: `test-image-v1,test-image-v2,test-image`

how can I remove test-image, or test-image from the string using bash script?

thx

Comment: Do you want a find and replace i. e. the result would be `,-v1,-v2,...` or do you want it to be interpreted similar to a .csv file and therefore the result should be `test-image-v1,test-image-v2,...`? Or another intepretation. It's currently not clear.

Comment: Do you need to handle the case where the string consists _only_ of the item to remove, with no prefix and suffix?

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output

Comment: BTW, in a significant set of real-world cases I'd probably try to structure code to avoid using comma-separated-strings as lists at all in the first place; bash natively supports associative arrays (what Go would call a `map[string]string` or Python would call a `dict[str,str]`), so you can use your strings (`test-image` &c) as keys in such a structure, and create or check their presence in constant time.

Answer (score 3):

Using the shell's built-in [parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) capabilities:

```
# takes a string with comma-separated items, then a list of items to remove
remove_string() {
  local string remove
  string=$1; shift
  for remove in "$@"; do
    case $string in *,"$remove",*) string=${string//,"$remove",/,};; esac
    case $string in "$remove",*)   string=${string#"$remove",};; esac
    case $string in *,"$remove")   string=${string%,"$remove"};; esac
    case $string in "$remove")     string=;; esac
  done
  printf '%s\n' "$string"
}
```

Invoked as:

```
$ remove_string 'test-image,test-image-v1,test-image-v2,...' test-image
test-image-v1,test-image-v2,...
$ remove_string 'test-image-v1,test-image-v2,test-image' test-image
test-image-v1,test-image-v2
$ remove_string 'test-image-v1,test-image,test-image-v2,...' test-image
test-image-v1,test-image-v2,...
$ remove_string 'blah,blah,blah' test-image
blah,blah,blah
$ remove_string 'test-image' test-image
```

...and the above also allows multiple items to be removed to be passed in a single call:

```
$ remove_string 'foo,bar,baz,qux,plugh' foo baz
bar,qux,plugh
```

Comment: When you want to reduce `"test-image,test-image,test-image,a"` to `a`, you must repeat the string_to_remove: `remove_string "test-image,test-image,test-image,a" test-image test-image test-image`. Perhaps create a while loop around the `case..esac` and break when you don't find a match.

Comment: @WalterA, minor quibble: should only require two instances of the argument for the use case you gave, because the `,${match},` case uses `${var//search/replace}` rather than `${var/search/replace}`. Otherwise, a valid point. :)

Comment: @WalterA, ...update more to your liking?

Comment: Yes, better this way. In the `Invoked` examples, I would use quotes. The user might have a string with a space and make the mistake to forget the spaces.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed you can run `sed 's/test-image,//g;s/,\?test-image$//'`

For instance:

```
echo "test-image,test-image-v1,test-image-v2,test-image" | sed 's/test-image,//g;s/,\?test-image$//'
```

This removes `test-image,` from the beginning or from the middle of a line and later removes `test-image` from the end of the line together with a preceding comma if it exists.

### Update

In order to process correctly strings where test-image is preceded by some other characters such as `prefix-test-image`, we need to consider four cases:

1. The string contains `test-image` only, so our pattern is `^test-image$`
2. The string starts with `test-image`, but it is followed by other names, so our pattern is `^test-image,`
3. The string ends with `test-image`, but is preceded by other names, so our pattern is `,test-image$`
4. And the general case, where `test-image` is between other names: `,test-image,`

So the final command would be `s/,test-image,/,/g;s/,test-image$//;s/^test-image$//;s/^test-image,//`

Example:

```bash
echo "test-image,prefix-test-image,test-image-v1,test-image-v2,test-image" | sed 's/,test-image,/,/g;s/,test-image$//;s/^test-image$//;s/^test-image,//;'
```

Comment: Right now you aren't distinguishing `test-image` from `prefix-test-image`, so this can change `test-image,another-test-image,test-image-2` to have `another-` left in the output standing alone.

Comment: great,  thx , it is the answer I am looking for

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```bash
images='test-image,test-image-v1,test-image-v2,...'
IFS=, read -ra imgs <<< "$images"
for i in "${!imgs[@]}"; do
  [[ ${imgs[i]} == "test-image" ]] && unset 'imgs[i]'
done
new_images=$(IFS=,; echo "${imgs[*]}")
declare -p images new_images
```

outputs

```
declare -- images="test-image,test-image-v1,test-image-v2,..."
declare -- new_images="test-image-v1,test-image-v2,..."
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to remove the string possible more times, you can use

```
echo "$string" |tr ',' '\n' | grep -v "^test-image$"| sed -rz 's/\n(.)/,\1/g'
```

Edit 1:
(requires GNU sed for `-z`, might not work on all platforms)

Edit 2:
An `awk` command for this:

```
echo "$string" | awk '
  BEGIN {RS="[,\n]"}
  $0 != "test-image" {outstring = outstring sep $0; sep=","}
  END {print outstring}
 '
```

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that this requires GNU sed and may not work on all platforms -- but good approach in general.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I would prefer `awk 'BEGIN {RS=","; ORS=","} $0 != "test-image" {print}'`, but I have a mistake in this approach.

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN {RS="[,\n]"; ORS=""} $0 != "test-image" {if (x) {print ","}; print; x=1} END { print "\n" }'` is working, but is too ugly for an answer.

Comment: Only thing I'd change about the awk approach is using `-v` to pass the string to remove out-of-band from the code.

Answer (score 1):

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean pure Bash program demonstrates a way to use Bash's built-in regular expression pattern matching (`[[ ... =~ ... ]]`) to remove an arbitrary number of arbitrary strings from a comma-separated list of strings:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

to_remove=$1
comma_string=$2

pre_rx='(^|^.*,)'
post_rx='($|,.*$)'

new_comma_string=$comma_string
while [[ $new_comma_string =~ ${pre_rx}"$to_remove"${post_rx} ]]; do
    sep=${BASH_REMATCH[1]: -1}${BASH_REMATCH[2]:0:1}
    new_comma_string=${BASH_REMATCH[1]%,}${sep#,}${BASH_REMATCH[2]#,}
done

printf '%s\n' "$new_comma_string"
```

- To use it, run it with the string to be removed as the first argument and the comma-separated list of strings as the second argument (e.g. `./progname 'test-image' 'test-image-v1,test-image-v2,test-image'`).
- See [mkelement0's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35924143/4154375) to [How do I use a regex in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35919103/4154375) for information about Bash's regular expression support.
- See [Extracting parts of strings (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Extracting_parts_of_strings) for an explanation of `${BASH_REMATCH[1]: -1}` and `${BASH_REMATCH[2]:0:1}`.
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `${BASH_REMATCH[1]%,}`, `${sep#,}`, and `${BASH_REMATCH[2]#,}`.