# Regular Expression - Pattern

Tags: regex, shell

I am new to Shell scripting. I am trying to write a code that should grep few lines from a huge file based on certain condition.

Contents of file, say **names.txt**

```
1 ae1aee2sonata om,vadodara,23-Aug-2016
2 chdc501ae om,patna,26-Aug-2016
3 chdc4326aee6 om,bhuvi,01-Oct-2016
4 ae3aee6prsons hqr,bangalore,29-Aug-2016
5 praaeei5 om,lucknow,11-Nov-2016
6 aetaeen6pana om,phanto,13-Oct-2016
```

and goes on for 500 or more entries.

Now, I am looking for output for the following :

1. Filter lines with only "aee" available in it. So, the output will look 
   like:

> ```
> 3 chdc4326aee6.om,bhuvi,01-Oct-2016
> 5 praaeei5 om,lucknow,11-Nov-2016
> ```

2. Filter lines with only "ae" and "ae + "aee" available in the file. So, 
   the output will look like:

> ```
> 1 ae1aee2sonata.hqr,vadodara,23-Aug-2016
> 2 chdc501ae.om,patna,26-Aug-2016
> 4 ae3aee6prsons hqr,bangalore,29-Aug-2016
> 6 aetaeen6pana om,phanto,13-Oct-2016
> ```

3. Filter lines with only "ae" from the file. So, the output will look like:

> ```
> 2 chdc501ae.om,patna,26-Aug-2016
> ```

Any suggestions please. You can point to a good place for getting more information about this, so I can learn.

Comment: This would be a good example on how to use regular expression on shell scripts
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737675/shell-script-how-to-extract-string-using-regular-expressions

Comment: Hi Tim, I trying with basic Shell scripting with bash shell

Comment: Similarly if you want to learn on regular expression, just google it and you will so may places to start with

Comment: You are going to need to use negative lookaheads to achieve what you want.  Can you try the following regex and let us know if it works: `^((?!aee).)*ae((?!aee).)*$`

Comment: command: `cat names.txt |grep '^((?!aee).)*ae((?!aee).)*$'` gives no output.

Comment: @Ram, does this regex yield good results: `.*ae[^e].*(aee)?.*` ? This is for lines that have ae and (ae + aee)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grep with option -P and lookahead

**The file:**

```
$ cat data.txt 
1 ae1aee2sonata om,vadodara,23-Aug-2016
2 chdc501ae om,patna,26-Aug-2016
3 chdc4326aee6 om,bhuvi,01-Oct-2016
4 ae3aee6prsons hqr,bangalore,29-Aug-2016
5 praaeei5 om,lucknow,11-Nov-2016
6 aetaeen6pana om,phanto,13-Oct-2016
```

**Find `aee` but not `ae` :**

```
$ grep -P '^(?:(?=.*aee[^e]))?(?!.*ae[^e]).*(aee)[^e]' data.txt 
3 chdc4326aee6 om,bhuvi,01-Oct-2016
5 praaeei5 om,lucknow,11-Nov-2016
```

**Find `ae` or `ae` + `aee` :**

```
$ grep -P '^(?:(?!.*aee[^e]))?(?=.*ae[^e]).*(aee?)[^e]' data.txt
1 ae1aee2sonata om,vadodara,23-Aug-2016
2 chdc501ae om,patna,26-Aug-2016
4 ae3aee6prsons hqr,bangalore,29-Aug-2016
6 aetaeen6pana om,phanto,13-Oct-2016
```

**Find `ae` only :**

```
$ grep -P '^(?!.*aee[^e])(?=.*ae[^e]).*(ae)[^e]' data.txt
2 chdc501ae om,patna,26-Aug-2016
```

Comment: @Ram: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it works for you.

Comment: **Thank You** Mr. Toto...To openly say, I really don't understand the statements. This really works out my problem...Is there a place for me to get to know more stuffs like this...I googled and googled..still googling....

Comment: @Ram: You will find a regex tutorial here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/  For `grep -P` just do `man grep`