# Linux output - find numbers between two /

Tags: regex, linux

Modifying the query to provide some more context.

I am writing a groovy script to get a list of objects
output s3://xyz/1/abc
       s3://xyz/2/lmo
       s3://xyz/6/hjl

I need to grep the largest number in middle (here 6).

On command line I tried 
echo "xyz/23/xyz/jhdids/dsd"|awk -F\/ '$0=$2'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\/' treated as plain`/'
23;

It works on command prompt. But when I try to embed it in my groovy script, it gives error.
In groovy - $4 has the value xyz/23/xyz/jhdids/dsd

aws s3 ls --recursive s3://xyz    | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4|awk -F\/ '$0=$2'}\'

Hope this elaborates my issue.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shell script. how to extract string using regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737675/shell-script-how-to-extract-string-using-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

```
<linux_command> | grep -oP "\/\K(\d+)(?=\/.*)"
```